# Why does my gpio button work when connected in hdmi but if not it automatically triggers the button in raspberry pi?

Tags: button, raspberry-pi3, gpiozero

I am still new in python and I am wondering when I switch from a desktop monitor to a 3.5 TFT LCD monitor and I tried to use a button if the hdmi is connected the gpio button works but if i remove it it automatically triggers the button without me pressing it. Btw, I use gpiozero for the button. Can someone help please?

Comment: Show us the code please

Comment: I literally used button = Button(4) and button.wait_for_press() . The button works if connected with an hdmi but without the hdmithe push button clicks without me doing anything